# Json.NET DeserializeObject named objects to 1 class

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm consuming data from a third party vendor via a rest api.

Snippet of JSON that the api returns:

```
{
    "invoice": {
        "id": "12345",
        "lines": {
            "line1": {
                "amount": 1,
                "amount_desc": "",
                "description": "Description 1",
                "tax_rate": "-1",
                "price": "100",
                "discount_pct": 0,
                "linetotal": 100
            },
            "line2": {
                "description": "Description 2"
            },
            "line3": {
                "amount": 1,
                "amount_desc": "",
                "description": "Description 3",
                "tax_rate": "-1",
                "price": "300",
                "discount_pct": 0,
                "linetotal": 300
            },
            "line4": {
                "description": "Description 4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how many "lines" the API can return, therefore I don't like to create classes for every line object.

My "Line" class looks like:

```
public class Lines
{
    public Line Line1 { get; set; }
    public Line Line2 { get; set; }
    public Line Line3 { get; set; }
    public Line Line4 { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Amount_Desc")]
    public string AmountDesc { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Tax_Rate")]
    public string TaxRate { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Discount_Pct")]
    public int DiscountPct { get; set; }
    public int Linetotal { get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize all Line1, Line2, Line100? to my single "Line" class?

Comment: Create another class with name lines and put only one property public List<Line> Lines{get;set;} and then try to convert it to C# object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deserialize this into a `Dictionary<string, Line>`:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Id
    { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Line> Lines
    { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Invoice Invoice
    { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize your JSON in the question as a `Data` object which contains only an `Invoice` property. That `Invoice` property is then of the `Invoice` type which contains the lines in the `Lines` dictionary.

The `line1` to `line4` strings become the keys in your dictionary, and the values are deserialized `Line` objects.

Comment: I don't know the exact amount of lines, can be 1, can be 100 lines.

Comment: And…? That is relevant why? Did you try my solution?

Comment: I tried but get an exception: Could not find member 'line1' on object of type 'Data'. Path 'invoice.lines.line1', line 1, position 207.

Comment: Show your actual JSON then, the one you posted in the question was incomplete/invalid. See the JSON I posted in my answer for a valid one that works with that `Data` class.

Comment: The JSON I posted was just a snippet, I just edited the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that the json the API is returning is very poorly done.  Lines should be an array of lines, not an object with N lines in it.  This would be the correct json:

```
{
    "invoice" : {
        "id" : "12345",
        "lines" : [{
                "amount" : 1,
                "amount_desc" : "",
                "description" : "Description 1",
                "tax_rate" : "-1",
                "price" : "100",
                "discount_pct" : 0,
                "linetotal" : 100
            }, {
                "description" : "Description 2"
            }, {
                "amount" : 1,
                "amount_desc" : "",
                "description" : "Description 3",
                "tax_rate" : "-1",
                "price" : "300",
                "discount_pct" : 0,
                "linetotal" : 300
            }, {
                "description" : "Description 4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I think asking them to correct their API would be the best way to go (for both parties).